# How to solve ThrottlingException in Hbase

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, throttling

I am using map-reduce job to read hbase, from time to time i receive

```
Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.quotas.ThrottlingException:
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.quotas.ThrottlingException: 
request size limit exceeded -         wait 0.00sec at
```

Because of this entire map reduce job gets killed, is there a way how to tell hbase to read slower? Or to tell it to wait and retry?

Answer (score 0):

setting hbase.client.pause and hbase.client.retries.number to higher values might help.

Comment: did not worked, I think hbase is not trying to do any retry when receives ThrottlingException. http://webmail.dev411.com/p/hbase/dev/155b72rnp9/throttlingexception-should-be-handled-by-client-was-re-vote-first-release-candidate-for-hbase-1-1-0-rc0-is-available

Answer (score 0):

The exception can be handled by overriding Mapper.run method, i have not found any document that is recommending this solution. It just works for me.

```
@Override
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    setup(context);
    try {

        while (true) {
            boolean wasResult;
            int retry_number=0;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    wasResult = context.nextKeyValue();

                    break;
                } catch (ThrottlingException te) {
                    retry_number+=1;
                    Thread.sleep(1000+200*retry_number);
                }
            }
            if (!wasResult) break;
            map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
        }
    } finally {
        cleanup(context);
    }
}
```